# How can you limit the hours entered for a specific task in Microsoft Project Server?

Tags: ms-project

I have projects where I want a task to have a set number of hours charged to it. If three people are charging to the project, 8 hours a day, and I specify that the project can only have 40 hours charged to it. Then all three of them can charge the first day, and then two of them will charge the next day, but the third one will have to charge to another task.

Is this possible?

Comment: the managers should not approve them. and get a new baseline and re-plan project again. or change team members ... or you define a new enterprise field (column) for project managers or time-sheet managers or default assignment owners to view maximum work and reject that work. and also define indicators to notify people  when actual work is greater than maximum work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find any way to do this in Microsoft Project Server 2007. I do not have a Microsoft Project Server 2010 installation so I can't tell you for that system.

However, In my experience tightly linking your project management tracking system to your billing system like this not a good idea. I have always viewed project management systems as ways to estimate, track my estimates to reality, and improve my estimates for the next time. Client billing and getting paid for my work was a discrete process. Even when the team's time sheet system was used to track project execution, I would adjust the billing and not the project tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that?  You are fudging your actuals to meet a goal.  Actuals are actuals.  Your team must charge what they work, all the hours they work it, and to the proper work package.

You will have variances.  If you come in with a zero variance, you cooked the books.  The only caveat to that is an LOE task for schedule.  That is always a variance of zero.

Further, if you do not collect honest actuals, you will not have the data you need to better your estimation in the future.  And the vicious cycle will continue.

Comment: I am not trying to limit the tracking of actual hours for the project. I have a PO that can only have a certain number of hours charged to it, and once all of those hours are charged, I want to charge to a new PO. I want to be able to do this automatically, where one task represents the first PO and the second represents the second PO. Once the hours of the first task are completed, it doesn't allow more hours and employees then charge to the second task.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Atlassian Jira for these kind of things. You will have control over both charged amout and the work calendar.